# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 4 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,64], [4,?]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got an error,

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 4 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,64], [4,?].
```

I wrote codes,

```
from keras import backend as K

print(input_encoded_m)
print(question_encoded)
match = K.dot(input_encoded_m, question_encoded)
```

print(input_encoded_m) shows `Tensor("cond_3/Merge:0", shape=(?, 68, 64), dtype=float32)` and print(question_encoded) shows `Tensor("cond_5/Merge:0", shape=(?, 4, 64), dtype=float32)`.I think dot method is not good to calcurate matrix has different rank,so I rewrite

```
from keras import backend as K
match = K.get_value(input_encoded_m * question_encoded)
```

But this error occurs:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 68 and 4 for 'mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [?,68,64], [?,4,64]
```

How can I calcurate `input_encoded_m` & `question_encoded`? What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which of the dimensions your actual number of inputs is, but the first dimension needs to be the same.

But for example you need to have shapes:

`(68, 64, 4)` and `(68, 4, 64)`

or

`(64, 68, 4)` and `(64, 4, 68)`

or

`(4, 68, 64)` and `(4, 64, 68)` etc..

But you have number of inputs `68` and `4`, these need to match.

You should checkout the examples given in the [here in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul).